# Secure Http Handler

Tags: sharepoint-server

I am writing an http handler for sharepoint 2010 application with anonymous access enabled, I want to query a sharepoint list and http handler will be used to receive request from jquery.

Everything working fine, application is configured for anonymous users, If I type handler url directly in the browser I can still see list items, Is there any way to check/restrict http handler to service request only if coming from web application?

If user type directly in the browser I don't want to show anything, or even if url is called from another application I don't want to return any result.

Answer (score 0):

Some ways:

1. checking the url and not respond (context.Request.RawUrl). http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/335968/Implementing-HTTPHandler-and-HTTPModule-in-ASP-NET
2. Set configuration in the web.config: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e0dzxdza(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: no both solution are discussing different things.